# What does the "&=" in this C# code do?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I came across some code that looks like this:

```
string someString;

...

bool someBoolean = true;
someBoolean &= someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");
```

Why would I use the bitwise operator instead of "="?

Comment: I consider that code rather ugly.  It's shorter, but it strikes me as a bit abusive to use a bitwise and when you really mean a logical and.  Also note that logical and supports short-circuiting and thus avoids the need to compute `someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");` when `someBoolean` is `true`.

Comment: @Brian: It's not a bitwise operator when applied to booleans.

Comment: @Guffa: Yeah, you're right.  [The MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) actually states that explicitly.  I would assume the standard does as well.

Comment: What does it mean to say "it's not a bitwise operator when applied to booleans?" Isn't a boolean just a 1-bit number? That is, is there any functional difference between a 1-bit bitwise operation and a logical boolean operation?

Comment: @JamieTreworgy a bool variable in C# is stored as 16 bits (2 bytes), but its values can be only 0000000000000000 and 111111111111111 so bitwise or not bitwise is the same. If a bool variable in C# could store other values (Like C) it would make a difference.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's not a bitwise operator when it's applied to boolean operators.

It's the same as:

```
someBoolean = someBoolean & someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");
```

You usually see the short-cut and operator `&&`, but the operator `&` is also an and operator when applied to booleans, only it doesn't do the short-cut bit.

You can use the `&&` operator instead (but there is no `&&=` operator) to possibly save on some calculations. If the `someBoolean` contains `false`, the second operand will not be evaluated:

```
someBoolean = someBoolean && someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");
```

In your special case, the variable is set to `true` on the line before, so the and operation is completely unneccesary. You can just evaluate the expression and assign to the variable. Also, instead of converting the string and then comparing, you should use a comparison that handles the way you want it compared:

```
bool someBoolean =
  "blah".Equals(someString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Bitwise operators are still bitwise operators when they are applied to System.Booleans. However, since C# sets 'true' equal to 1, they wind up having the same truth table as the boolean operators. However, any non-zero integer can serve as a valid true value. See http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/6wYCZ3QmNUClKXiYi113Pw for an example.

Answer (score 10):

It's the equivalent of `+=` for the `&` operator.

Answer (score 5):

It is short for:

```
someBoolean = someBoolean & someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx) (&= operator).

Answer (score 3):

As Guffa pointed, there IS a difference between & and &&. I would not say you can, but rather you SHOULD use && instead of & : & makes your code geeker, but && makes your code more readable... and more performant. The following shows how :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch Chrono = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (false & Verifier())
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        Chrono.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(Chrono.Elapsed);

        Chrono.Restart();
        if (false && Verifier())
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        Chrono.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(Chrono.Elapsed);
    }

    public static bool Verifier()
    {
        // Long test
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
someBoolean = someBoolean & someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");
```

which, in this case, before someBoolean is true, means

```
someBoolean = someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the short form of this:

```
someBoolean = someBoolean & someString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("blah")
```