# The &= Operator Equivalent

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
bool funcExecuted = false;
bool result = false;
Func<bool> returnFalse = () =>
{
    funcExecuted = true;
    return false; 
};
result &= returnFalse();

string msg = funcExecuted?"Executed":"Not Executed";
Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

**Expected result:**

- I expected to get the message of `Not Executed`

**Actual result:**

- I got the `Executed` message.

**Conclusions:**

`result &= returnFalse();` is compiled to `result = result & returnFalse();` rather than `result = result && returnFalse();` (I expected the latter).

My question is, why is that?

I would expect it to be the other way around. We all use the `&&` operator much more commonly than the `&` operator and I would expect it to be the "default behaviour".

---

**Update:**
Most answers seems to answer the wrong question.
I am aware of the fact that the difference between `&&` and `&` is that `&&` is short-circuiting, whereas `&` always evaluates both operands.

The question was why does `a &= b` translates into `a = a & b;` rather than `a = a && b;`

Comment: Presumably it would be called &&= in that case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "&=" in this C# code do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556027/what-does-the-in-this-c-sharp-code-do)

Comment: @MarkPattison Thought about it too, was googling to check if this operator exists, and I am just unaware of it.

Comment: well its a perception you have. As we know x+=y means = x+y and I am personally use to this perception. Thus for x &= y I will expect x = x & y

Comment: Why would you expect a compound assignment operator which only uses one `&` to be equivalent to using `&&` rather than `&`? That seems an odd expectation to me.

Comment: `&=` is a bitwise operator in C, C++, Java and even JavaScript. As a member of the C-like "dysfunctional family" of languages, C# sticks with the established pattern when it comes to fundamentals like this.

Comment: @jonskeet I figured that the more commonly used operator should deserve a more convenient way for typing, and since I am not aware of C# having 3 characters operators (e.g. `&&=` as suggested) this would be the appropriate one. perhaps it is only me...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346001/why-are-there-no-or-operators

Comment: @AviTurner: I can understand thinking there should be an `&&=` operator... but that's not the same as expecting the `&=` operator to use `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion that you fail into is that when there is a difference when you use `&&` and `&` on numeric values but there is not when you use it on booleans in context of bytes.

Then only difference is that when you use `&&`, you get as short-circuiting.

```
boolean result = false  & true; //bitwise AND
boolean result = false && true; //logical AND
```

There is no difference in result. Then only difference is how CPU will deal with it.

In that case when you are using operator `&=` for boolean it is equal to use `result = value & value`.

The assumption that short-circuiting, will be used when you use `&=` is not easy to understand. The argument that `&&` is used more often than `&` does not find place here. Because the `&` is bitwise logical operator and `&&` is logical. So it is natural that `&=` mean what it mean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Clear and Well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You got "Executed" message  because of

```
Func<bool> returnFalse = () =>
{
    funcExecuted = true; //THIS !!!!!!
    return false; 
};
```

and this

```
string msg = funcExecuted?"Executed":"Not Executed";
```

`funcExceuted` is ALWAYS (in the scope of provided code) `true`.

The code of binary `&` you wrote is actually converted to what you expect:

```
result &= returnFalse();
```

is

```
result = result &  returnFalse();
```

but the thing is that on condition you don't check for `result`, but for `funcExceuted`.
change it ti `result` and you will get expected behavior from code.

What about

> why is that?

it's `C#` language syntax, for the same reson

`left+=right` is converted to `left = left + right`

Comment: He's not asking why the result is what it is, he wants to know if there's a shorthand for `var a = a && b` or why `&=` results in `a & b` and not `a && b`.

Comment: @germi: he is asking why the code is not printing "Not executed", answer is: the codintion checks wrong variable.

Comment: @Tigran He expected the function not to execute at all, as `result && returnFalse()` would short cicruit because `result` starts out `false`.

Comment: @Rotem: but he wrote & and NOT &&. He knows what is & and what is && and knows differences between them, but whoud expect x&=y equal to x = x&&y, so my answer adresses that issue *too*.

Comment: @Tigran I guess the only real question here is 'Is there an `&&=` operator in c#'.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key differences between `&&` and `&` is that `&&` is short-circuiting, whereas `&` always evaluates both operands.

The `result &= returnFalse();` is eqivalent to `result = result & returnFalse();`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of that. As I wrote, I have expected it to be equivalent to `result = result && returnFalse();`

Comment: If you knew it, why ask the question? Or were you hoping someone here would communicate with the gods of C#?

Comment: @david.pfx Sorry for the typo. I meant `result = result && returnFalse();` - comment updated. The question is about is why is that.